# XPath - find upcoming birthdays

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

How can I find contacts with upcoming birthdays, say within 10 days, given the following XML?

```
<contacts>
  <contact>
    <name>bob</name>
    <birthday>1978-05-06</birthday>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>mary</name>
    <birthday>1955-06-06</birthday>
  </contact>
  <contact>
    <name>john</name>
    <birthday>1998-05-06</birthday>
  </contact>
</contacts>
```

I've got the following xpath but it breaks down because the month-from-dateTime returns an integer (5) instead of a '0' padded string (05).  Is there a way to build a date in Xpath that will accept integer parameter for day, month, year instead of my ungly hack concatenating strings?

```
/contacts/contact[days-from-duration(xs:dateTime(concat(year-from-dateTime(current-date()),'-',month-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday)),'-',day-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday)))) - current-date()) < 10]
```

Comment: The following handles the left padding but there must be a better way: `/contacts/contact/xs:dateTime(concat(year-from-dateTime(current-date()),'-',substring(concat('00', month-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday))), string-length(month-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday))) + 1, 2),'-',substring(concat('00', day-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday))), string-length(day-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday))) + 1, 2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a yearMonthDuration to add so enough years to move the date to the current year:

```
/contacts/contact[ 
  xs:dateTime(birthday) + xs:yearMonthDuration("P1Y") * (year-from-dateTime(current-date()) -  year-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday))) < current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration("P10D")
]
```

And to check that the birthday is not in the past (for works like let to avoid typing it all twice here):

```
/contacts/contact[ 
  for $thisYearBirthDay in xs:dateTime(birthday) + xs:yearMonthDuration("P1Y") * (year-from-dateTime(current-date()) -  year-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday)))  
  return $thisYearBirthDay >= current-date() and $thisYearBirthDay < current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration("P10D")
]
```

However, to actually make it work, you need to check the current and the *next* year, in case the current-date is around xmas, e.g.:

```
/contacts/contact[ 
  exists((for $delta in (0, 1) return xs:dateTime(birthday) + xs:yearMonthDuration("P1Y") * ($delta + year-from-dateTime(current-date()) -  year-from-dateTime(xs:dateTime(birthday))))[. >= current-date() and . < current-date() + xs:dayTimeDuration("P10D")])
]
```